# Ubuntu 16.04 lags and boots up incredibly slow

Tags: 16.04, performance

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with an i5 processor and 4 GB of ram.

I have basically two issues, which are likely related each other.

The first I have is that Ubuntu boots up in something like 5 minutes or more.

Here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
52.846s networking.service
45.072s dev-sda5.device
43.418s irqbalance.service
43.225s apport.service
43.065s grub-common.service
43.033s ondemand.service
42.742s speech-dispatcher.service
34.712s ModemManager.service
31.854s lightdm.service
28.636s apparmor.service
24.052s NetworkManager.service
22.293s accounts-daemon.service
13.635s polkitd.service
10.237s gpu-manager.service
 8.179s systemd-udevd.service
 6.594s console-setup.service
 6.538s udisks2.service
 6.467s thermald.service
 6.450s pppd-dns.service
 5.701s colord.service
 5.087s rsyslog.service
 4.704s plymouth-start.service
 3.883s upower.service
 3.621s keyboard-setup.service
 3.476s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
 3.377s avahi-daemon.service
 3.193s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
 3.070s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
 2.887s systemd-journald.service
 2.613s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
```

Moreover, all the things starts to lag depending on what I do. I checked through `htop` to look for reasons, but it basically doesn't show anything that is heavily running the CPU.

Comment: did you check if your RAM has some empty space while running? there might be some processes that are consuming all of your memory

Comment: The 'systemd' output says 52 seconds. Where does the "5 minutes or more" come from?

Comment: I thought the time was the sum of all the times above actually. Cause it really took a while to boot up. For sure not 52 seconds. When I boot the system it goes in a black screen for a while, then a page with some green OKs in a black background pop up and eventually ubuntu starts off. 
I checked the memory and indeed the swap was used. But why does it keep lagging even after have closed all the applications? Do you guys have any other suggestions on tools that I can use to monitor performances? Htop does not show anything strange.